# How to write a custom assert function that accepts assert messages like this: assert(false) << "assertion" << " failed";

Tags: c++

I want to write an assert function that works like this:

```
//the following expression outputs "assertion failed" to std::err and then terminates the program
assert(false) << "assertion " << "failed";
```

What I have so far is this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class AssertHelper
{
    public:
        AssertHelper(bool state):assert_state(state){};
        AssertHelper operator<<(const std::string &mesg){
            if(!assert_state){
                std::cerr << mesg << std::endl;
                std::cerr.flush();
                exit(-1);
            }
            return *this;
        };

    private:
        bool assert_state;
};

AssertHelper assert(bool cond){
    return AssertHelper(cond);
}

int main(){
    assert(false) << "assertion" << " failed";

}
```

But my way of implementing it only displays the first part of the message "assertion". How can I print the second (and potentially third, fourth...) part of the message before terminating?

Comment: What does `AssertHelper::operator<<()` return?

Comment: My mistake. It is supposed to return the object calling `operator<<()`. I made an edit to my post to fix the mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minimal correction:

```
const AssertHelper& operator<<(const std::string& mesg) const
{
    if (!assert_state)
        std::cerr << mesg;
    return *this;
};

~AssertHelper()
{
    if (!assert_state)
    {
        std::cerr << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Remarks: `operator<<` should return a reference, not a value; `bool assert_state;` can be marked as `const`; calling `flush()` after `<< std::endl` is superfluous.

Answer (score 3):

Don't check the assertion every time you stream something into your object. Use the fact that your object will be destroyed at the end of the statement by checking and flushing in `AssertHelper`'s destructor.

Your `operator<<` should be as simple as this:

```
AssertHelper& operator<<(const T &v) {
  _message << v;
  return *this;
}
```

Note that you return a reference to the same object, making the next call to `<<` stream into the same object! Make `_message` a member variable that you can stream into like a `std::stringstream`. And in the destructor do this:

```
~AssertHelper(){
  if(!assert_state){
    std::cerr << _message.str() << std::endl;
    exit(-1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `operator<<` always prints the error message regardless of the `assert_state` value. This is not supposed to be happening.

Comment: @Evgeny `_message` is supposed to be a std::string member variable, so, no.

Comment: You're absolutely right, corrected my answer to use a `std::stringstream`.

Comment: Why would you want to use a temporary buffer?